# SQL Server Dynamic SQL Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use a dynamic sql query due to having a variable table name. I am unable to resolve the correct syntax to use in the Where clause for @ParentItem. I either get a message that i must declare the scalar variable or incorrect syntax near h where @ParentItem = N'123-123h'. I have tried various versions of including single quotation marks without success.

```
EXEC(
'SELECT j.job
 FROM Malt'+@Number+'
 RIGHT Join job j on BOMID LIKE ''%''+ j.job
 WHERE BOMID IN (Select ''.'' + j.job                   
FROM job j
WHERE j.item = '+@ParentItem+' AND j.type = ''S''')
GROUP BY j.job')
```

Comment: show that part, do you have a DECLARE line for ParentItem?

Comment: if u have the declaration, put the entire statement into a string variable and EXEC(@str)

Comment: ParentItem is passed from a front end so there is no Declare statement

Answer (score 0):

seems like missing a right parentheses after S and the quotation mark surrounding parentItem; try this:

```
EXEC(
'SELECT j.job
 FROM Malt'+@Number+'
 RIGHT Join job j on BOMID LIKE ''%''+ j.job
 WHERE BOMID IN (Select ''.'' + j.job                   
FROM job j
WHERE j.item = ''' + @ParentItem +''' AND j.type = ''S'') GROUP BY j.job')
)
```

Comment: sorry, missed the last line off. it end with a group by clause

Comment: ok, so you don't need to add the parentheses I added after S, just the 3 quotations surrounding parentItem

Comment: Also, if @Number is not a string datatype, you'll need to cast it as such.